# How can a superclass object which is assigned the value of a subclass object execute an overloaded method of subclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, overloading, derived-class, base-class

```
class A
{
    private int m;
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println(m);  
    }
}
class B extends A
{
    int n;
    B(int b)
    {
        this.n = b; 
    }
    public void display()
    {
        super.display();
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
class trial
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B(10);
        a = b;
        a.display();
    }
}
```

In the above code, how does the variable `a` on invoking the `display()` function execute the subclass `display()` - the subclass `display()` is of type `B` and is not supposed to exist in an object with type `A`. I got this doubt because, apparently superclass variables can reference subclass objects. 
However, they will be unable to access elements(variables,functions etc) present in the subclass. But the above code is in violation of that principle.

Comment: Because of the line: `a = b;`.

Comment: I think you should read up about polymorphism and overriding of methods. `display()` exists in `A`, that's why it knows it exists. `B` overrides it.

Comment: I understand that B overrides it- but when I assign ```a = b;``` shouldn't the variable a only be able to access the display function in the base class - cause it is of the base class's type? The overriden method's existence shouldn't be known to 'a'. For example : 'a' isn't aware of the existence of the variable n that was declared in the subclass. If I tried to access n as follows : ```a=b;System.out.println(a.n);``` it throws me an error. Clearly the base class object cannot acces the subclass's variables- then how can it access the subclass's overridden function?

Comment: Because it's overridden. That's the whole point of overriding a method. It tells the object: "Run your method called `display()` that has no parameters". If the object is of type `A`, it will run the original `display()`. If it's of type `B`, it will ride its own version of `display()`. But you can't access anything that wasn't *declared* in the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code when the below code is executed

**a = b;**

variable a refers to a B object. Since A is the superclass of B it can hold the reference of Child Class instance.
It is equivalent to **A b = new B(10);**
now if we call **b.display()**;

//B's version of display() is called.

This is called Runtime Polymorphism in JAVA. Using which you can override the parent class method in the child object. But you cannot access the instance variable of Child class or the method which is only present in Child Class.

Please read 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-method-dispatch-runtime-polymorphism-java/

Comment: @ANIRUDHMS Can you accept the answer if it helped you.